# Toggle text using one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create javascript or jquery, whichever is simplest, using a toggle function, where the button toggles between two articles. The first article contains only text and the second article contains three paragraphs plus figures (images and fig captions).

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: And what ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)/representative) HTML would you be working with?

Comment: You really need to show some code and what you have tried.

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function from jquery example [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#example-0)

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery toggle function, as well as the hide and show functions.

```
$('button').click().toggle(function () {
        $('item1').show();
        $('item2').hide();
    },
        function () {
            $('item1').hide();
            $('item2').show();
        });
```